# How to affect data inside a loop with angucomplete-alt?

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently working on the following **update** form :

```html
<div ng-repeat="mission in missions">
    <angucomplete-alt id="finalClient"
                selected-object="setSelectedFinalClient"
                remote-url="@Url.Action("GetClients", "ManageMission")/?query="
                title-field="Name"
                initial-value="{{mission.FinalClient}}"
                minlength="1"
                override-suggestions="true"
                match-class="angucomplete-match"
                input-class="form-control"
                template-url="@Url.Content("~/Templates/required-angucomplete-alt.html")"></angucomplete-alt>
</div>
```

```js
misApp.controller('ManageMissionController', ['$scope', '$http', 'urlService', 'httpGetService', function ($scope, $http, urlService, httpGetService) {
$scope.missions = [];

/* This function is called when page is loaded and data are affected to the previous array */
$scope.loadMissions = function () {
    $http.get(urlService.missionsUrl).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.missions = data.Missions;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.error(data);
    });
};

$scope.setSelectedFinalClient = function (selected) {
   if ($scope.checkIfObjectIsDefined(selected)) {
        // If : the selected object comes from the autocomplete list
        if (typeof selected.originalObject.Name !== 'undefined') {
            mission.finalClient = selected.originalObject.Name; // I want to affect this value to item of $scope.missions which is currently modified
        }
        // Else : new client (only a string))
        else {
            mission.finalClient = selected.originalObject; // I want to affect this value to item of $scope.missions which is currently modified
        }
    }
    else {
        mission.finalClient = null;
    }
};  
}]);
```

My goal is to update the right item in the $scope.missions array, but I receive the follwing error :

> mission is undefined

I understand why it doesn't work, but I have no idea how to solve the problem.

**EDIT:** data are correctly loaded in $scope.missions

Comment: Try to use `missions` array directly insteaf of mission varibale in the ng-repeat loop: `selected-object="missions[$index].FinalClient"`,  `initial-value="{{missions[$index].FinalClient}}"`

Comment: selected-object="mission.FinalClient" works, the problem is the selected-object could be a simple string or a complex object